# how to get values from spring controller to Angular js

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

How to get this value in angular js page to display the details in JSP page.please some one help to get this value and view it in Angular JS using Ajax call.

```
@Controller

public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/iwill", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView searchd() {


        return new ModelAndView("search");
    }


     @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public @ResponseBody void  search(HttpServletResponse res,HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException {

     List<Employee> data =  employeeService.listEmployeess();
       JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
           for (Employee e : data) {
               JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(e);
               array.put(jsonObject);
           }
        res.getWriter().append(array.toString());

       }
    }
```

my Angular js page:

### Here i do no how to get my data.if i simply (http://localhost:8080/sdnext/search.html )use this url its showing json data if i implement in angular js its not throwing error but no data's get displayed.

```
  <!doctype html>
<html >
    <head>
        <title>Spring MVC + AngularJS Demo</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        function Hello($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('http://localhost:8080/sdnext/search.html').
                success(function(response) {
                    $scope.employees = response.data;
                });
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app">

        <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>salary</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>BloodGrp</th>
        <th>Aids</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>

<tbody  ng-controller="Hello">
 <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees"> 
 <td>{{employee.empId}}</td>
  <td>{{employee.empName}}</td>
   <td>{{employee.empAge}}</td> 
   <td>{{employee.salary}}</td> 
   <td>{{employee.empAddress}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.bloodgrp}}</td> 
    <td>{{employee.aids}}</td>
     <td>{{employee.weight}}</td> 
     </tr> </tbody> 
            </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

**

My JSON response i given below:
This  im getting while using the url http://localhost:8080/sdnext/search.html but i dono how to use this in Angular js to display my data in jsp page.

**

```
[{"empId":1,"bloodgrp":"0-ve","empName":"krishnaKumars","weight":78,"aids":"negative","empAge":23,"salary":15000,"empAddress":"madurai"},{"empId":2,"bloodgrp":"o-ve","empName":"Archanasundar","weight":68,"aids":"Negative","empAge":31,"salary":50000,"empAddress":"chennai"},{"empId":4,"bloodgrp":"o-ve","empName":"Kabali","weight":78,"aids":"negative","empAge":23,"salary":201300,"empAddress":"Madurai"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make an ajax request from angular $http.get at "/search"

this would work

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

     public List<Employee> search( ) throws IOException {

     return  employeeService.listEmployeess();

       }
```

you got a mistake there

```
function Hello($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('http://localhost:8080/sdnext/search.html').
                success(function(response) {
                    $scope.employees = pesponse;
                });
        }
```

$scope.employees = response.data is the correct one

should be like this

```
<script>
angular.module("app",[])
        .controller("Hello",function ($scope,$http){
     $scope.getData = function() {
            $http.get('http://localhost:8080/sdnext/search.html').
                success(function(response) {
                    $scope.employees = response.data;
                });
        }
    });

        </script>
```

also

```
<tbody  ng-controller="Hello" ng-init="getData ()">
```

check these tell me if that worked

Comment: if i  write produces it showing error   (The attribute produces is undefined for the annotation type RequestMapping)

Comment: try this 

produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE

Comment: Its asking me to change as header,param

Comment: please bro help im stucked for 2 weeks im new to spring mvc fresher

Comment: check the edited answer also post your error message
also have you annotated the class with @RestController?

Comment: Please any on help me its difficult for me to do

Comment: add your errors and edit your post with full code if your can

Comment: k bro wait but its not throwing any error in console page simply it intimating not to use produces

Comment: check my edited answer , so the problem now is on angular request spring controllers works fine right?

Comment: i need to give response.data instead of response

Comment: NOw also its not displaying the data bro

Comment: ng-controller="Hello" should be inside ng-app="your appName"
edit your post with your angular js file you are close!

Comment: I edited is it correct bro but while running its showing like this

Comment: {{employee.empId}} {{employee.empName}} {{employee.empAge}} {{employee.salary}} {{employee.empAddress}} {{employee.bloodgrp}} {{employee.aids}} {{employee.weight}}

Comment: without json how can we pass data from controller to jsp page

Comment: you have a repository to clone so i can help you further ? you propably need to take a look on documentation and http examples with angular

Comment: Is there any other way to do brother because im sturggling for 2 weeks